# Social Tables API: Difference between legacy and non-legacy delete API endpoints

Tags: social-tables

When I attempt to delete an event with this API endpoint, a Not Authorized response is returned. The event was created with the Layout Automation endpoint.

```
DELETE /4.0/events/{event_id}
```

However, when I try with this endpoint, the delete is successful.

```
DELETE /4.0/legacyvm3/teams/{team}/events/{event}
```

What is the difference between the two endpoints? I am building an interface that many social tables users at different companies will use, so I would like to make sure that I implement the interface in a way that will support all users.

The event ID that I am testing with is 2332155

Also, after deleting with the Legacy endpoint, the event still shows up in the user interface (on Events tab) of Social tables (a Not Found error occurs when attempting to interact with the event). Why does the deleted event still show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the `/4.0/legacyvm3` and `/4.0` endpoint sets map to different internal systems; the `/4.0/legacyvm3` endpoints use a numeric ID system and the `/4.0` endpoints use different, alphanumeric identifiers.

You can find the `/4.0` event identifier for an event using the `GET /4.0/events-by-legacy-id/{legacy_id}` endpoint. After grabbing the ID from the response body, you can use it to interact with the `/4.0` event endpoints!